# A little help deleting value from an global variable

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch some form data but something interrupts,

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $data = $_POST;
}
?>

<form action = "page.php" method="post">
Username<input type="username" name="username"/><br/>
Password<input type="text" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

okay, the above outputs to 
Array ( [username] => '' [password] => '' [email] => '' [submit] => Submit )

Okay,  if i am to send this into database. i should be sending it without the key submit and value submit. How do you do it?

Comment: Remove it or just don't use the entire `$_POST` array and take only the inputs

Comment: @Rizier123 +1.  Also, you should be sanitizing your input.  Might consider looking into the filter_input() function.

Comment: i saw always see that pop up in netbeans while accessing global variables. I am new to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset it.

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    unset($_POST['submit']);
}
```

A better practice would be to save it to a new variable and make changes there.

Comment: WOW, That was really quick. Thank you veryyyyy muchhh :)

Comment: i've been doing the same, adding it to a new variable and its even done sending queries to sql